# Cordova Windows Phone 8 Play Local File Sound

Tags: file, cordova, audio, windows-phone-8, media

How can I play a local mp3 file in the www folder? 
Example: I need to play the following file : 'www/audio/button.mp3'. So:
1) I install the Cordova media and the media capture plugin.
2) I add the following code in the DeviceReady event handler :

```js
var media=null;

function onDeviceReady()
    {

        alert("ready");
        addSoundEffects();

    }

function addSoundEffects(){
  
    var soundUrl=getMediaUrl("/audio/button.mp3");
  
    media=new Media(soundUrl,mediaLoaded,mediaError);
    alert('after');
}



function getMediaUrl(s){
    if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") return "/android_asset/www" + s;
    return 'www'+s;
}


function mediaLoaded(){
    alert('Media loaded correctly');
}

function mediaError(e) {
    alert('Media Error');
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

3) I run the application on my windows phone device, but it just stopped on the media=new Media(soundUrl,mediaLoaded,mediaError); row. I can see the "after" alert, but the function above doesn't call mediaLoaded neither mediaError, i don't know what to do.

NOTE: I think that the path is not the problem, otherwise it should just call the mediaError callback. I notice that the 'Media' variable is undefined, i don't know if can help.

Thanks for answer, i have been working on this from 3 hours and i can't find anything on google!

Comment: did you got a solution for this/?

Comment: No, i can't play local mp3 file, i always got some kind of error, only on windows phone!

Answer (score 0):

try to add '/' before www. It works in my apps